# Repurposing Old Subfloor Planks

Tags: wood, woodworking

I am pulling up my old subfloor (my house was built in 1928) in the attic which consists of tongue and groove wooden planks. Any ideas for repurposing them as a wood working project?

[image]

Comment: I would have thought it was just unfinished flooring, myself, but what do I know.

Comment: There's no way for us to answer this question for you, as a "correct" answer completely depends on your personal preference.

Comment: You might try taking this to the new woodworking.stackexchange area.

Comment: That sounds like a better place for this, thanks!